# Proving $g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=2x+3$ is one to one.

Tags: functions, logic, solution-verification

Working on the book: Daniel J. Velleman. "HOW TO PROVE IT: A Structured Approach, Second Edition" (p. 242)

> 2. We can define a function $g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ by the rule that for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $g(x) = 2x + 3$.

- Assume $a,a' \in \mathbb{Z} \land g(a)=g(a')$

  - $g(a)=g(a')$
  - $2a+3=2a'+3$
  - $2a=2a'$
  - ...

I know $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and division is not closed in $\mathbb{Z}$. Now, my question is: how can I justify $a=a'$ ?

Comment: The division takes place in $\mathbb R$. If you were in $\mathbb Z$ you could use $2(a-a')=0\implies a=a'$.

Comment: Thank you. Is the application of $g$ that tells me that I'm in $\mathbb{R}$ ? How can I know formally in which set I'm working on ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you, @fleablood. Of course, but what would be the justification for using division ? I'm missing a subtle detail, I think.

Comment: If $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ and $ka = kb$ then $ka$ and $kb$ are multiples of $k$ and you can divide by $k$ to get an integer.

Comment: I understand your confusion, and I'm trying to come up with the best explanation.  The arithmetic you are doing is the arithmetic of the real numbers and even if you are restricting yourself to the integers you are working in the reals.  If $2a =2a'$ then $a = a'$ because they *are* reals and division is closed. What you don't know is that if $2a=2a'\in \mathbb Z$ you *do* know $a = a'$ but you don't know that $a, a'$ are integers.  However you do know they are integers as they com from the domain of $g$.  ... I don't think you are missing something subtle, but that you don't *need* subtlety.

Comment: Your last comment here and below the other answer fully address  my question. I see now that I didn't fully understand the problem. Thank you very much, @fleablood. Let me see if I get what you're saying. $2$ is a constant, and when doing operations with it, I need to take into account the greater set it belongs. As $\mathbb{R} \supset \mathbb{Z}$ and division is closed there, I can multiply $2 \in \mathbb{R}$ by its multiplicative inverse. Am I close ?￼

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what set you're working in by knowing $g(a), g(a') \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore performing the following computation in $\mathbb{R}$ allows you to deduce $a = a'$ from $2a = 2a'$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: That's true but even if you had $h: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ via $h(x)=2x + 3$.  If you had $b,b'\in \mathbb Z$ and figured $2b = 2b'\in \mathbb Z$ you can *still* divide by $2$ and conclude that $b=b'$.  It doesn't matter than division isn't closed in $\mathbb Z$ because it *is* closed in $\mathbb R \supset \mathbb Z$.  So even if you had $2k = 2m = 7$ we *know* $k=m$.  The only thing we *don't* know is whether $k,m\in \mathbb Z$ (in this example they *aren't*) but even if they *aren't* the *are* equal.  But it the OP question they are because $a,a'\in \mathbb Z$.